# Axes, labels, and titles are hidden or overlapped/occluded by the plot when the dataSource is updated

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I'm using Core Plot successfully in an Objective-C app.  I'm writing a new app in Swift and I'm having some trouble.  Before I set a `dataSource` for my graph, the axes appear correctly and as expected.  See the following screenshot:

[Screenshot With Correct Axes](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p3pks23x2gr2g16/BeforeData.png)

The problem is that when I set a `dataSource`, the data is rendered properly, but the axes disappear.  See the following screenshot:

[Screenshot With Axes Gone](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qftk52vaox8put9/AfterData.png)

I want the axes, labels, and titles to remain visible when the data is rendered.  There are lots of possible causes, and I've tried to rule out all the ones I can think of.  Here's what I've tried:

- The problem isn't the axis title positions or graph padding, because they show up correctly at first.
- I read one post saying `graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = false` should work. That didn't do it.
- I tried setting the graph and plot area fills to `nil` to try to reveal the titles if they were occluded by the fill.  A view behind the graph was revealed, but not the titles.
- I tried various values for `graph.topDownLayerOrder`, trying to ensure the titles were the topmost item, esp. on top of the plot area. Note the docs say the default is axis titles on top, so I didn't expect this to fix it.
- I confirmed with the debugger that the axis labels were not set as hidden.

Thanks in advance for any help, and thank you Eric for sharing this sweet library with us!

Following is my source code:

```
class TemperatureGraph: CPTGraphHostingView, CPTPlotSpaceDelegate {

    // Just needed to retain dataSource
    var dataSource: CPTPlotDataSource?

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func setupGraphWithSession(session: Session?) {
        self.configureGraph()
        self.configurePlot()
        self.configureAxes()
        if (session != nil)
        {
            self.configureDataSource(session!)
        }
    }

    func configureGraph() {
        let graph: CPTGraph = CPTXYGraph(frame: self.bounds)
        graph.applyTheme(CPTTheme(named: kCPTSlateTheme))

        graph.title = "Temperature History (°F)"

        graph.paddingTop    = 0.0;
        graph.paddingBottom = 0.0;
        graph.paddingLeft   = 0.0;
        graph.paddingRight  = 0.0;

        //        graph.titleDisplacement = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20)
        graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop    = 30.0;
        graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 50.0;
        graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft   = 50.0;
        graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight  = 10.0;

        // This doesn't help
        // graph.fill = nil;
        // graph.plotAreaFrame.fill = nil;

        // This doesn't help
        // graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = false

        // This doesn't help either
        //graph.topDownLayerOrder = [NSNumber(unsignedInt: CPTGraphLayerTypeAxisTitles.value)]

        // Some themes have a rounded border around the plot area. It looks bad since we removed the insets, so remove the border too.
        graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
        graph.plotAreaFrame.cornerRadius = 0;
        self.hostedGraph = graph
    }

    func configurePlot() {
        let graph = self.hostedGraph
        var plot = CPTScatterPlot()
        // Make the data source line use curved interpolation
        // plot.interpolation = CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved;

        var lineStyle: CPTMutableLineStyle = plot.dataLineStyle.mutableCopy() as CPTMutableLineStyle
        lineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
        lineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.redColor()
        plot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
        // For some reason, areaBaseValue isn't visible in swift. It's in the header and in Objective-C, don't know why it's not seen here.
        //plot.areaFill = CPTFill(color: lineStyle.lineColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2))
        //plot.areaBaseValue = NSDecimalNumber.zero()

        graph.addPlot(plot)
    }

    func configureAxes() {
        let graph = self.hostedGraph
        let plot = graph.plotAtIndex(0)

        // The timestamps are large, which would make an inordinant number of axis label text by default, so to even render the graph in under a minute, simplify the axes.
        var axisSet: CPTAxisSet = graph.axisSet
        var axisTitleStyle = CPTMutableTextStyle()
        axisTitleStyle.color = CPTColor.blackColor()
        axisTitleStyle.fontName = "Helvetica-Bold"
        axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12

        var xAxis = axisSet.axisForCoordinate(CPTCoordinateX, atIndex: 0)
        xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone
        xAxis.title = "Time"
        xAxis.titleOffset = 15
        xAxis.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle


        var yAxis = axisSet.axisForCoordinate(CPTCoordinateY, atIndex: 0)
//        yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone
        yAxis.title = "Temperature (°F)"
        yAxis.titleOffset = 25
        yAxis.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle
    }

    func configureDataSource(sesh: Session) {
        self.dataSource = TemperatureDatasource(session: sesh)

        let plot = self.hostedGraph.plotAtIndex(0)
        plot.dataSource = self.dataSource
        plot.plotSpace.scaleToFitPlots([plot])
        plot.plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = true
        plot.plotSpace.delegate = self
    }

    func plotSpace(space: CPTPlotSpace!, shouldScaleBy interactionScale: CGFloat, aboutPoint interactionPoint: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func plotSpace(space: CPTPlotSpace!, willChangePlotRangeTo newRange: CPTPlotRange!, forCoordinate coordinate: CPTCoordinate) -> CPTPlotRange! {
        // Adjust axis to keep them in view at the left and bottom;
        // adjust scale-labels to match the scroll.
        var allowedRange = newRange
        if (coordinate.value == CPTCoordinateY.value) {
            let space = self.hostedGraph.defaultPlotSpace as CPTXYPlotSpace
            allowedRange = space.yRange
        }
        return allowedRange;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the axes always cross at (0, 0). I suspect your plot data doesn't cover that point, so `scaleToFitPlots` pushes (0, 0) outside the visible plot area and hides the axes. You have several options:

1. Use `axisConstraints` to lock the axes to a certain spot (e.g., the left edge of the plot area for the y-axis).
2. After calling `scaleToFitPlots`, update the `orthogonalPosition` of each axis within the corresponding plot range.
3. After calling `scaleToFitPlots`, expand the plot ranges so they include zero (0), if needed.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I went with option 1 and it worked great.